# Inserting a "timestamp" formated entry to an mySQL table using php

Tags: php, sql, insert, format, timestamp

I have a mySQL table with a column formatted as "timestamp". I am trying to insert a value using a php script to no avail. Below I have shown a couple unsuccessful approaches, can any one demonstrate how to do generate a properly formatted value using php?

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tableName`(`timeColumnName`) VALUES ('".strtotime("now")."')") or die(mysql_error());

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tableName`(`timeColumnName`) VALUES (now())") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You can also use date('Y-m-d h:i:s')

Comment: What mysql_error() it is reflecting ?

Comment: I tested this and its working fine..echo your query.. run it in mysql and test whether it is working or not.. INSERT INTO `tableName`(`timeColumnName`) VALUES (now())

Comment: Hi Swapnesh, I'm not getting an error, the value is just not showing up in the table. Is the column you are inserting to formated as "timestamp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date()` function in `php`, like this,

`$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName(timeColumnName) 
VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example for you to insert the timestamp. It depends which time format you would like to store in the MySQL DB.

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', now() );
$query = "UPDATE table SET datetimefield = $mysqldate WHERE...";
```

If you wish to store the timestamp as a number, you have to change the type of your field in DB to number type.